# Vuex: Mount() and computed() is executed from a same component, my data is not loading on first?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using `action` to get all products and then using `computed` method on the same  `component` to display data. Here is the `component`:

```
<template v-for="product in allProducts">
    <div class="ap-table-content">
        {{ product.product_name }}
    </div>              
    <div class="ap-table-content">
        {{ product.code }}
    </div>
</template>
```

And the `vue` to render `allProducts` is

```
export default {

        computed :{
            ...mapGetters([
                'allProducts'
            ]),
        },
        mounted(){
            this.$store.dispatch('fetchAllProducts');
        },

    }
```

And on my store.js I have set my store like:

```
state: {
    allProducts : {}
},
getters: {
    allProducts: state=>{
        return state.allProducts;
    }
},
actions:{

 fetchAllProducts : async({commit, state})=>{
            await axios.get('/products')
                .then(response => {
                    commit('storeProducts', response.data);

                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        },
```

}

**SOLUTION:**
It was my mutator. I was assigning a lump of my array in the object without getting the `state.property` where `computed` lost its `value`.

```
storeProducts(state, data){
             Object.assign(state.allProducts, data);
}
```

This mutation was the culprit. 
Can someone give me better option to attach data at state?

Comment: Can I see `storeProducts` mutations?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. You're trying to use a getter called `allProducts` but what you declared in your store `getters` is `allproducts` and that's why your data is not displaying.

Modify your getter function to `allProducts` instead of `allproducts`.

```
getters: {
    allProducts: state=>{
        return state.allProducts;
    }
},
```

Also I noticed that you used `store: { allProducts: {} }` inside your module instead of `state`.

> [image]

It's okay if you are exporting it as `state` later but if not, then you should change it to `state: { allProducts: {} }`

Comment: no.. its not working. On first, no data but it fetches the data and commits to my state. Second time i click on it I have data. Only at the first its not working. It is not reactive I guess

Comment: @ReyYoung Are you exporting the `store` key as `state` later in your module cause it should be `state` instead of `store`.

Comment: where? i'm exporting it as a store

Comment: @ReyYoung I added a screenshot of what I mean. It would be better if you create a codesandbox that would reproduce the problem, it can be resolved faster.

Comment: aw sorry i tried to reproduce my problem .. so that is a typo sorry